# clear each thing after doing achieving a specific task

Tags: c#, .net

i am working on an software in which i want to clear each thing after doing achieving a specific task, like clearing all the fields, list view etc etc and i've to write the a lot of things to be cleared off, like the code of my new button is:

```
 private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtProductCode1.ReadOnly = false;
        txtInvoiceNo.ReadOnly = false;
        cmbCustoemerType.Enabled = false;
        cmbCustomerName.Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        txtProductCode1.Text = null;
        txtWageName.Text = null;
        txtWageCost.Text = null;
        btnFirst.Visible = false;
        btnPrevious.Visible = false;
        btnNext.Visible = false;
        btnLast.Visible = false;
        cmbProductName.Enabled = true;
        txtQty.ReadOnly = false;
        txtPercant.ReadOnly = false;
        txtDiscount.ReadOnly = false;
        cmbCustoemerType.Enabled = true;
        cmbCustomerName.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
        dtp1.Enabled = true;
        btnSave.Text = "&Save";

        cmbCustoemerType.Text = null;
        cmbCustomerName.Text = null;
        txtInvoiceNo.Clear();
        txtDiscount.Clear();
        txtGrandTotal.Clear();
        txtProductName.Clear();
        txtSalePrice.Clear();
        txtQty.Clear();
        txtTotal.Clear();

        txtExtraWages.Text = null;
        lvExtraWages.Items.Clear();
        lvTransaction.Items.Clear();
        lblCount.Text = null;
        lblNetTotal.Text = null;
        txtPercant.Text = null;

        txtInvoiceNo.Text = invoice.ToString();
    }
```

is there any way to get rid of writing the code again n again, like i need to enable one thing which i've disabled here on another button so i have to write reverse code of this to achieve the task and it's really annoying! is there any other way to do this?

### EDIT:

tried following code:

```
private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
           //using setboxdefault function
            SetTextBoxDefaults();

            cmbCustoemerType.Text = null;
            cmbCustomerName.Text = null;
        cmbCustoemerType.Enabled = false;
        cmbCustomerName.Enabled = false;
        cmbProductName.Enabled = true;
        cmbCustoemerType.Enabled = true;
        cmbCustomerName.Enabled = true;

        button5.Enabled = true;
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;  
        button1.Enabled = true;          
        btnFirst.Visible = false;
        btnPrevious.Visible = false;
        btnNext.Visible = false;
        btnLast.Visible = false;          


        btnSave.Text = "&Save";

        lvExtraWages.Items.Clear();
        lvTransaction.Items.Clear();

        lblCount.Text = null;
        lblNetTotal.Text = null;

        dtp1.Enabled = true;

        txtInvoiceNo.Text = invoice.ToString();
    }

    private void SetTextBoxDefaults()
    {
        var textBoxes = GetControls(this, typeof(TextBox));
        foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
        {
            TextBox.Clear();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control control, Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControls(ctrl, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
    }
```

but it's giving error on  `TextBox.Clear();` , error is Error   4

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Clear()'
```

Please let me know where i am mistaking..!!

Comment: Have you tried looping through the controls collection?

Comment: @Tim No , sadly i don't know about it

Comment: If WPF, you could just instantiate a new ViewModel. Is this WPF? If so, look into MVVM.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569641/reset-all-the-items-in-a-form

Comment: Judging by how he doesn't know what he's doing, it's probably winforms.

Comment: @Magus yeah i am working on winforms

Comment: You really should use WPF. It was invented in part because of the inherent ugliness of winforms.

Comment: @Magus now at this stage where i've already done approx 1500 lines of code, how can i shift to WPF?? it's nightmare dude

Comment: Yeah, but if it's 1500 lines of property assignments, you'll probably have far less than half that afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim has suggested, you can iterate though the controls and set each one accordingly..

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetControls(ctrl,type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetComboBoxDefaults();
    SetTextBoxDefaults();
    SetButtonDefaults();
}

private void SetComboBoxDefaults()
{
    var comboBoxes = GetControls(this, typeof(ComboBox));
    foreach (var comboBox in comboBoxes)
    {
        ((ComboBox)comboBox).Enabled = false;
        ((ComboBox)comboBox).Text = null;
    }
}

private void SetTextBoxDefaults()
{
    var textBoxes = GetControls(this, typeof(TextBox));
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        ((TextBox)textBox).Clear();
    }
}

private void SetButtonDefaults()
{
    var buttons = GetControls(this, typeof(Button));
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        ((Button)button).Visible = false;

        if (button.Name == "btnSave") ((Button)button).Text = "&Save";
    }
}
```

You can also have separate *GetControl* methods so that it returns a specific type of Control, reducing the need to cast to derived types.

update for edit:

You are using the `TextBox` type instead of the variable name in the `foreach` loop. Update it to use `textBox` (lowercase), not `TextBox` (pascal) see below:

```
private void SetTextBoxDefaults()
{
    var textBoxes = GetControls(this, typeof(TextBox));
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        ((TextBox)textBox).Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: woww, finally some nice and clean code... i am surely gonna try this

Comment: @JackFrost you may need to add some specific conditioning based on control name, if it differs from all other controls of the same type (as shown in SetButtonDefaults())

Comment: now this error is coming Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it's cool working now, but if i've to null some textboxes but not the all?? @d.moncada

Answer (score 3):

Remember to stay **DRY**

- [Don't](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html)
- [Repeat](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself)
- [Yourself](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html)

Partition the reset logic into suitable, small methods that reset a logical grouping of controls. Then invoke those methods where and as needed.

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in several such cases is this:

```
void SetTextBoxReadOnly(bool val, param TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    if(textBoxes != null && textBoxes.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach(TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
        {
            if(textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.ReadOnly = val;
            }
        }
    }
}

void SetControlEnabled(bool val, param Control[] ctrls)
{
    if(ctrls != null && ctrls.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach(Control ctrl in ctrls)
        {
            if(ctrl != null)
            {
                ctrl.Enabled = val;
            }
        }
    }
}

// etc set of methods for similar situations.
// there methods can be invoked as

...
...
...

SetTextBoxReadOnly(true, txtProductCode1,
                         txtInvoiceNo,
                         txtQty,
                         txtPercant,
                         txtDiscount);
```

Comment: @AhsanMughal - There might be some negative side-effect of this approach, but I am yet to see anything. Moreover it helps me keep the code clean and relevant.