# How can one refresh TabContol inner controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

First, I read this [Reset all the items in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569641/reset-all-the-items-in-a-form)

It was a great help until I realised all my controls are inside a `TabControl` containing itself several tabs in which there are all the common controls i.e. textbox, datetimepicker, datagrigview, etc....

Then I tried `MyTabControl.Controls.Clear()` but this deleted all tabs in the form.

How can I implement this [Reset all the items in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569641/reset-all-the-items-in-a-form) in a TabControl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
foreach (Control c in GetAll(myTabControl))
{
    ResetAllControls(c);
}
```

in which ResetAllControls is the method in your [referenced link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569641/reset-all-the-items-in-a-form) and

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl))
                                  .Concat(controls);
}
```

from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button).

Comment: AWESOME man. It has just solved the issue. What made you think we'd need to use GetAll (also that's a method logic for me. Never seen one (I 'm a C# newb))

Comment: glad I could help